Upper/Lower bounds of real-analytic functions with infinite Taylor series
For example, in 1-D, given some positive increasing polynomial $p(x) = a_1x+\ldots+a_nx^n$, $p(0) = 0$, there exists constants $b_1,b_2$ such that for $x<\delta$, for some $\delta > 0$, we have that
$$
b_1 x^{n_1} \leq p(x) \leq b_2 x^{n_1},
$$
where $n_1$ is the smallest exponent on $x$. Additionally, the same property holds for real-analytic functions.
I was wondering if there's an 2-D analogue of this property in regards to real-analytic functions that do not have a finite Taylor series expansion. Additionally, lets assume that these functions are strictly increasing along lines intersecting the origin.
If my function is a polynomial it is pretty straightforward. For example, consider $f(x,y) = x^2 + (x^2+y^2)^2$. It follows that
$$
(x^2+y^2)^2 \leq f(x,y) \leq 2 (x^2+y^2).
$$
for $(x,y)\in B_{\delta}$ for some $\delta > 0$. The lower bound is determined by the largest exponent and the upper bound is determined by the smallest exponent.
Now, if $f(x,y)$ is instead defined in terms of some infinite Taylor series can one still find such inequalities? Intuitively, it feels like the upper bound could still be found, but a lower bound seems far more difficult. Any advice would be appreciate.

I proved an analogue result for power series of a complex variable sometimes ago in this Q&A. You can adapt the proof to the $\Bbb R^2$ case nearly verbatim.

@DanieleTampieri I didn't read your answer too closely, but it seems you only get an upper bound that is a polynomial by bounding the remainder. Can you get a lower bound by a similar argument?

As to a local upper   bound  of the form $b|x|^m$ there is essentially nothing to prove. The  maximum  admissible $m$ is the  order of the first non-vanishing  differential  $d^mf(0)$, so any coefficient $b> \frac{|d^mf(0)|}{m!}$  works:  we have  $f(x)= \frac1{m!}d^mf(0)[x^m]+o(|x|^m)$ so $ |f(x)|\le \big(\frac{|d^mf(0)|}{m!} +  o(1)\big)|x|^m \le b|x|^m $  locally at $x=0$

You can use the Weierstrass preparation theorem and recursively apply the 1-D result. The theorem asserts that an analytic function $f(x,\mathbf{y})$, for which $f(0,0)=0$, can be written as a product $f(x,\mathbf{y}) = W(x,\mathbf{y}) g(x,\mathbf{y})$, where $W(0,0) \ne 0$ and
$$
  g(x,\mathbf{y}) = x^k + g_{k-1}(\mathbf{y}) x^{k-1} + \cdots + g_0(\mathbf{y})
$$
is a Weierstrass polynomial of some degree $k$, with analytic coefficients such that $g_i(\mathbf{y}=0) = 0$.
By continuity, there is some $\delta > 0$ such that $0 < C_1 \le W(x,\mathbf{y}) \le C_2$ on $(x,\mathbf{y}) \in B_\delta$, so
$$
  C_1 g(x,\mathbf{y}) \le f(x,\mathbf{y}) \le C_2 g(x,\mathbf{y})
$$
reduces the bounds to those on $g(x,\mathbf{y})$. If we have bounds on the coefficients $b_i(\mathbf{y}) \le g_i(\mathbf{y}) \le c_i(\mathbf{y})$ for $|\mathbf{y}| \le \delta$, then
$$
  x^k + b_{k-1}(\mathbf{y}) x^{k-1} + \cdots + b_0(\mathbf{y})
    \le g(x,\mathbf{y}) \le
  x^k + c_{k-1}(\mathbf{y}) x^{k-1} + \cdots + c_0(\mathbf{y}) .
$$
To get the coefficient bounds, you can now apply the above steps recursively, possibly shrinking $\delta$ as necessary. Once you get to the 1-D case, you can terminate by using the bounds given by monomials. The result will be of the form
$$
  b(x,\mathbf{y}) \le f(x,\mathbf{y}) \le c(x,\mathbf{y}) ,
$$
where $b$ and $c$ are polynomials. If your original function only had positive Taylor coefficients, I suspect that all the intermediate upper and lower bounds should also have positive coefficients, but I'm not sure. Perhaps some other trick could be used if a negative lower bound appears for one of the coefficients at an intermediate step.
The lower bound $b$ is in general not going to be a monomial, but if it does have only positive coefficients, you could drop from it as many terms as you would like. Applying this idea to your example
\begin{align*}
  f(x,y) &= x^4 + 2 (y^2 + 1) x^2 + y^4 \\
    &= W(x,y) \left(x^2 + \frac{1}{2} + 2y^2 - \sqrt{y^2 + \frac{1}{4}}\right) \\
    &= W(x,y) (x^2 + y^4 - 2 y^6 + \cdots)
\end{align*}
gives the bounds
$$
  B (x^2 + y^4) \le B_2 (x^2 + B_0 y^4) \le f(x,y) \le  C_2 (x^2 + C_0 y^4) \le C (x^2 + y^4) .
$$
The outer bounds follow from the inner ones by setting for instance $B = \min(B_2, B_2 B_0)$ and $C = \max(C_2, C_2 C_0)$. Switching around the roles of $x$ and $y$, $f(x,y) = y^4 + 2 x^2 y^2 + (x^4 + x^2)$ is already in Weierstrass form and the resulting bounds are
$$
  B (y^2 + x^2)^2 \le f(x,y) \le C (y^4 + x^2 y^2 + x^2) .
$$
The middle coefficient in the upper bound could also be any other positive constant.

This is a detailed answer! However, I should have been slightly more specific with my question. I'm curious if you could always make the bounds (upper/lower) of the form $b_i(x^2+y^2)^{k_i}$ for some $b_i,k_i > 0$.

I think I may have answered my question with that comment. As you can always find polynomials as upper/lower bounds and as you can always do the "Euclidean distance" upper/lower bound with polynomials I can obtain the desired bounds. (With the caveat of somehow avoiding the lower bound becoming negative)

@Doofenshmert It seems to me it would be the case of clarifying better  what assumptions  are you  taking on  $f(x,y)$ and what  you are asking on  the  local  upper and lower bounds  you want, $g\le  f\le h$.

It seems you are asking for a non-negative lower bound that has an isolated zero at the origin: recall  that even if   $f(0)=0$ and $f$ is strictly increasing along  every radial direction, it may vanish e.g. on a parabola, like  $f(x,y):=(y-x^2)^2$, so that one can’t put  anything like $b(x^{2m}+y^{2m})$ below it in a nbd of the origin,  as you were asking in  a comment.
